# Check if part of string is in another string

Tags: matlab

I have a cell called FileName. 'a' and 'b' and others are in that cell. There is two types of strings which either includes say, drink or juice.

```
a = 'xxx_drink.txt';
b = 'xxx_juice.txt';
c = 'drink';
d = 'juice';
```

I'm trying to use an if statement that if 'c' is a part of 'a' then I want to store 'a' into a specific variable. If 'd' is a part of 'b' then I want to store it into another specific variable.

How do I go about this to solve this in MATLAB?

Comment: If I google with your question title plus 'matlab', the first result is [`findstr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findstr.html) which then directs me to [`strfind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html). Do either of these functions meet your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`contains`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contains.html) function find one string within another and returns a logical value. If string contains specified pattern then the function returns `true` and `false` otherwise. Use following:

```
FileName = {'xxx_drink.txt', 'xxx_juice.txt'};
pattern = 'drink';
idx = contains(FileName, pattern);
```

The first element of `idx` vector will be `true`,  the second will be `false`. To get cell elements that contains your pattern use

```
DrinkNames = FileName(idx);
```

or

```
DrinkNames = FileName(contains(FileName, 'drink'));
```

Also you could use a string,  string array or character vector instead of cell.

**Note**, the function was introduced in Matlab R2016b.

Comment: Keep in mind that `contains` was introduced only in R2016b

Comment: @EBH, yes. This notice is on linked page.

Comment: I know, but that should be mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use [`strfind`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html)..

```
amatched = '';
a = 'xxx_drink.txt';;
c = 'drink';
% Check if 'c' is a part of 'a'
if ~isempty(strfind(a, c))
    amatched = a;   % Assign to some variable     
end
```

`strfind` returns an empty array if no match is found, hence the `isempty` check.

Comment: You could remove `~` and `isempty`: `if strfind(a,c)`. Not sure which option is more readable

Comment: @LuisMendo I think I didn't make my question clear. Basically I have a cell full of names which either contain juice or drink. They are loaded from text files. If juice matches string then I want only the juice text files in a specific variable and vice-versa for drink.

Comment: So, with data `s = {'xxx_drink.txt' 'xxx_juice.txt'}; p = 'juice';`, your probably want `ind = cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(strfind(x,p)), s); s_juice = s(ind); s_nojuice = s(~ind);`